# Counting Inversion c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, mergesort

I am trying to implement a counting inversion algorithm using nested loop and merge sort. However, I have keep getting error messages like

for the nested loop implementation.And the nested loop algorithm sometimes does not work (It returns 0 incorrectly for a few times). And the merge sort algorithm crashes from time to time, has error message

> double free or corruption (out)

and returns 0 incorrectly like the nested loop algorithm. The main also does not work well in my opinion..

Comment: Please read the site guidelines. You are supposed to extract a minimal example from the code causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
count_inversions_fast(array, (int)sizeof(array)) << endl;
```

You cannot determine runtime size of array using `sizeof` this way. It will always be `sizeof(int*)` (more genrally size of a `void*`). It will be 4 bytes on 32-bit platform, and 8 bytes on 64-bit platform. It will always give constant compile time size. You need to use:

```
count_inversions_fast(array, values.size()) << endl;
```